# regex on Ocaml not matching single letter strings, numbers, and spaces?

Tags: regex, ocaml

I want to match commands like

```
a c x y
```

where a is the letter "a", c is any letter (a-z, A-Z), and x is a integer and y is an integer (x and y are suppose to coordinates). a, c, x, and y should be seperated by a single space

So I wrote up this regex

```
string_match (regexp "a [a-zA-z] [0-9]+ [0,9]+") str 0
```

But when I run it in utop

```
utop # let str = "a c 7 12";;
val str : string = "a c 7 12"                                                       
utop # string_match (regexp "a [a-zA-z] [0-9]+ [0,9]+") str 0;;
- : bool = false
```

I get false...

I've also tried regex `a[ ][a-zA-z][ ][0-9]+[ ][0,9]+` to match the spaces, but that also hasn't worked

If anyone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `y`, your regex is this: `[0,9]`. I believe it should be `[0-9]`. (Note the "," vs. the "-"). `[0,9]` will match the characters 0, comma, and 9. Your specification says that `y` is an integer, suggesting that `[0-9]` is what you want.

So:

```
a [a-zA-z] [0-9]+ [0-9]+
```

should work.

Also, consider "anchoring" your regex by beginning it with ^, which matches the beginning of the input, and ending it with $, which matches the end of the input.

So something like this:

```
^a [a-zA-z] [0-9]+ [0-9]+$
```

Comment: so would `^a [a-zA-z] [0-9]+ [0-9]+$`ensure that `"a c 7 12 alkjdflajflkjalkfdja"   `won't be matched?

Comment: correct. The 2nd regex I provided would fail unless the input ended after "12"